# Java Menu how to call main method from different class?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm making a game for a school project and trying to call the main method from a different package and class how can I do it?
I have the main method for my game here :

```
//Main method I want to call
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Display display = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(display);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle("Space Invaders");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    display.start();
}
```

And this is my code that I've created for my menu and my action listener for button to start and run the main method for the class

```
    //Menu/button I have created
public class test 
{
    public test ()
    {
        frame();
    }
    public void frame() 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(720,720);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b1 = new JButton(" Action Listener");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {

            }
        });
        p.add(b1);
        f.add(p);

    }

public static void main (String[]args) 
{
    new test();
}
```

Comment: You should never call `main` yourself, it´s automatically called upon startup. Or do you want to call another process?

Comment: UnholySheep
I'm trying to call the main method from another class to the test class when the button is clicked

Comment: Technically `main` is just a `static` function as any other, so you can just call it using `MyClass.main(myArgs)`. However as `main` should not contain any logic itself, this is rarely a good idea. Instead you should extract the actual logic into some own class or function and call this instead.

Comment: I think a [mcve] would make it easier for people to provide you with an answer that would resolve your problem.